# Помогите с поставлением запроса в терминал mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, консоль

Задача состаяла в том, что-бы создать таблицу articles в базе test_db. (привет всем кто смотрел Хауди)
Запрос должен был выглядеть так:

CREATE TABLE articles (id INT(11) PRIMARY A_I ,
title VARCHAR(255),
text TEXT ,
categorie_id INT(11), 
pubdate DATETIME CORRENT_TIMESTAP ,
views INT);

Но mysql отказался это обробатывать: ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: Во-первых, телепаты в отпуске и никто не сможет угадать что именно в синтаксисе нет так. Поэтому приводите __полный текст ошибки__. А во-вторых, я за телепатов сегодня и `CORRENT_TIMESTAP` это из другой галактики, наверно. Правильное написание __CURRENT_TIMESTAMP__.

Comment: ошибка:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A_I , title VARCHAR(255), text TEXT , categorie_id INT(11), pubdate DATETIME CUR' at line 1

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP я исправил

Comment: `A_I` что такое?

Comment: В php myАdmin'e это означало, что если я не указываю номер id то он ставится сам, по порядку.

Comment: Это флажок в phpmyadmin так называется. А в Mysql это разворачивается в `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: В phpmyadmin даже опции есть показа запроса на создание таблицы.

Comment: у меня нет возможности использовать phpmyadmin по этому я ушёл в терминал.Где можно посмотреть как эти команды выглядят в терминале?

Comment: О каких командах речь?

Comment: О камандах которые в терминале выглядят по одному а в phpmyadmin'е по другому.Что бы больше таких проблем не происходило.

Comment: Откройте mysql руководства и изучайте.